# How to align ggplot title with window rather than plot grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In `ggplot2` version 0.9 the behaviour of the alignment of a plot title changed. Whereas in v0.8.9 the alignment was relative to the plot window, in v0.9 the alignment is relative to the plotting grid.

Now, whereas I mostly agree that this is desirable behaviour, I quite often have very long plot titles.

**Question: Is there a way of aligning the plot title with the plot window rather than the plot grid?**

I'm looking for an solution that does automatic alignment of the plot. In other words, manual alignment using `hjust` would not work for me (I run this on hundreds of plots for each project).

Any solution that used `grid` directly is also acceptable.

---

Some sample code and plot: (Notice how the title gets truncated at the right of window).

```
dat <- data.frame(
  text = c(
    "It made me feel very positive to brand X", 
    "It was clear and easy to understand",
    "I didn't like it al all"),
  value=runif(3)
)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(text, value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  opts(title="Thinking about the ad that you've just seen, do you agree with the following statements? I agree that...") +
  theme_bw(16)
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In ggplot2 0.9 you can easily change the layout.

```
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(text, value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  opts(title="Thinking about the ad that you've just seen,\ndo you agree with the following statements?\nI agree that...") +
  theme_bw(16)

gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
gt$layout[which(gt$layout$name == "title"), c("l", "r")] <- c(1, max(gt$layout$r))
grid::grid.draw(gt)
```

Perhaps, in the future version, ggplot2 will provide consistent interfaces for tweaking the layout.

[image]

Comment: you can also change the truncation by changing clip to false.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is an easier way to do this with ggplot2_2.2.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution under ggplot2 2.2.1.  A function arranges the title text object over the top center of the ggplot.

```
library(gridExtra)

# A function that puts a title text object centered above a ggplot object "p"
add_centered_title <- function(p, text){
    grid.arrange(p, ncol = 1, top = text)
}

# Create the chart from your sample data
 test_chart <- ggplot(dat, aes(text, value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw(16)

# Usage:
add_centered_title(test_chart,
                   "Thinking about the ad that you've just seen, do you agree with the following statements? I agree that...")

# Or you can pipe a ggplot into this function using the %>% dplyr pipe:
library(dplyr)
test_chart %>%
  add_centered_title("Thinking about the ad that you've just seen, do you agree with the following statements? I agree that...")
```